# Display & push Multiple image using javascript & html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im basic developer just wanted to push images one after other when an new image is been selected by user ,

following is my javascript :-

preview.js

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#fileupload").change(function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
            dvPreview.html("");
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var img = $("<img />");
                        img.attr("style", "height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-top: 20px;");
                        img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                        dvPreview.append(img);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                } else {
                    alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                    dvPreview.html("");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Html

Index.html

```
    <div id='file'>
         <label for="fileupload" style="margin-right:5px;">Group Image/Logo</label><br>
         <input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
          <div id="dvPreview">
          </div>
    </div>
```

This code displays the image perfectly , but only in single instance( thumbnail gets changed every time he selects an image) .

What is neccessary to just push & show the thumbnail of all the images that user wants to upload ? .

Searching google , Points which can be usefull :-

using `Array` &
 using `foreach` loop

Any one can explain the proper syntax ? It would be great . Thank you .

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VK_7/agzxxwgy/)

Comment: You are cleaning DIV on each call: `dvPreview.html("");`  http://jsfiddle.net/agzxxwgy/1/

Comment: Yes got 90% what i wanted .... :) ... now how to display the latest selected image as first , how can that be obtained ?

Comment: `dvPreview.prepend(img);` ?! http://jsfiddle.net/agzxxwgy/2/

Comment: 100%  obtained what i needed . Thank you . Some silly mistakes though :p